# mql4 custom indicator. how to delete drawings my indicator drew on chart when deleting indicator

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I wrote a custom indicator that draws some rectangles on chart.
but i want this drawings get deleted when i delete indicator from chart.
is there any way to make this objects dependent to my indicator so by deleting the indicator objects get deleted too.

I try `OnDeinit()`but it does not triggered by deleting indicator